# Does F-35 flight stick have a trackball?

Tags: feature-identification, f-35, sidestick

There is a [trackball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackball)-looking thing on the side of F-35's side stick.
What is this? Is this actually a trackball?

[image]

There is also another round looking "button", although a bit different from the first one, on the lower back of the stick:

[image]

(The images are from [here](https://www.essexindustries.com/products/f-35-joint-strike-fighter-sidestick-grip/))

Comment: Looks very similar to the button low on the left side of the stick.  My guess is it's just another button, but I can't find any public documentation on the F-35 HOTAS controls.

Comment: @ErinAnne You can see in the pictures that the red button on the front has a conventional cylindrical cap like older generations of flight sticks, why would they choose a different cap design just for those two buttons? so I doubt it's just a button ... (and the one on the back isn't very clearly visible, it could be a hat switch)

Comment: The red one is likely the Weapon Release.  It isn't uncommon for other buttons on the stick not to match that; take a look at the A-10, F-22, and F-16 sticks to compare.

Comment: You could always send off for a copy of Essex Industries' manual for their side-stick.

Comment: M. Linux, why did you edit to remove the second image?  It was helpful, I'd suggest adding it back, because most people aren't going to click on the "from 'here'" link and thus will never see it--  thnx

Comment: quiet flyer, I removed that one to avoid confusion, because it seemed a little bit different from the side button.

Comment: quiet flyer, I included the second image again, with some clarification.

Comment: PS, a bit late to mention, but wouldn't a very small trackball be difficult to manipulate with a gloved hand/ finger?

Comment: quiet flyer, You could cut the glove's finger tips; and I actually saw some pictures of US fighter pilots wear such gloves as part of their flight suit.

Comment: quiet flyer, For example this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6p-v5Nky7U/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That appears to be a button, not a trackball.**

From pg. 17 in a presentation, *Active Stick & Throttle for F-35 - Joseph Krumenacker - NAVAIR Flight Controls / JSF Vehicle Systems - 16 October 2008*, found [here](https://pdfcoffee.com/f35-ais-krumenacker-sae-081016ppt-pdf-free.html):

It is used to engage/disengage stick sensitivity in hover. Inadvertent movement of the stick would disengage the altitude hold.

Engaging that S-5 button increases the force to needed to 'disengage'.

> [image]
>
> solution was a pilot-engageable “gripper” mode, in
> which an altitude-hold augmentation could be
> quickly engaged and disengaged
> – with gripper engaged, longitudinal stick breakout
> force is significantly increased to prevent
> inadvertent disengagement
>
> Pros
>
> - Hover stick force is “significantly higher” and provides pilot direct tactile feedback and
>   confirmation that the flight control system is in control of height axes
> - Push through or paddle off to begin vertical landing
>
> Cons
>
> - Remembering to select height hold
> - More buttons required